# When using shorthand echo, how come double echo in functions work?

Tags: php

How come this works (strict mode enabled):

```
<? function test() { echo 'hello world'; } ?>
<?= test(); ?>
```

and this doesn't:

```
<?= echo 'hello world'; ?>
```

Comment: `<?php echo echo 'hello world'; ?>`

Comment: echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct). echo (unlike some other language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot always be used in the context of a function.

Comment: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)` on `<?= echo 'foo'; ?>` . Doesn't this say all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
<?php
$foo = 'foo';
?>
```

Then these all produce the exact same output, the word 'foo':

```
<?= $foo ?>
<?= 'foo' ?>
foo
<?php echo $foo ?>
```

Whatever the "argument" inside the code `<?= ... ?>` is, it gets output. If it's a function call, the function is executed and its return value is the output. If it's just a value (variable, fixed string/integer), then that value is output.

`echo` is language construct and can be treated like a function call in some cases, but it does **NOT** have a return value.  So

```
<?= echo $foo ?>
```

echoes out `$foo`'s value via the echo command, but then echoes nothing else since `echo` itself has no return value.

Now, if it was

```
function myecho($foo) {
   echo $foo;
   return $foo;
}

<?= myecho('foo'); ?>
```

Then you get this:

```
foofoo
^^^---echo inside the function
   ^^^---- <?= implicit echo
```

as the output.

Answer (score 2):

Because it calls the function and then outputs the return value of the function.  Since the return value is nothing, the echo inside gets called and then 'nothing' (`NULL`) gets printed.

Comment: I don't think this is technically correct echo does not return its output.

Comment: Its not echo thats returning something.  If the OP were to `var_dump(test())` the result would be the echo, and then `NULL` would be what would be dumped (because the function being called doesn't return anything). effectively the short tags are calling `echo NULL;`

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. You are right because echo returns null :)